# Cannot filter new users by creation date on mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, users-page

Steps to repro:

1. Navigate to any Stack Exchange site -> Users -> show new users.
2. Attempt to change the filter from "reputation" to "creation date."
3. Observe that the filter link changes to "creation date" for a split second and then returns to "reputation" without reloading or filtering any of the users.

I would expect to be able to filter new users by reputation on mobile web.

- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: Reproduced also on a desktop computer using the mobile web, it's not device specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed and with you in the next build.